# How to find start time of last GPS route

Tags: mysql, sql, time, gps

I have data from GPS trackers.
Let's say something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_gps` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `speed` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `tracker_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and some sample data:

```
  ('1', '5', '07:00', 'car'),
  ('2', '10', '07:10', 'car'),
  ('3', '0', '07:20', 'bus'),
  ('4', '0', '07:30', 'car'),
  ('5', '0', '07:40', 'car'),
  ('6', '0', '07:50', 'car'),
  ('7', '20', '08:00', 'car'),
  ('8', '40', '08:10', 'bus'),
  ('9', '15', '08:15', 'car'),
  ('10', '0', '08:32', 'car'),
  ('11', '0', '08:40', 'car'),
  ('12', '0', '08:52', 'bus'),
  ('13', '12', '09:10', 'car'),
  ('14', '0', '09:25', 'car'),
  ('15', '0', '09:30', 'car'),
  ('16', '0', '09:35', 'car'),
  ('17', '10', '09:41', 'car'),
  ('18', '5', '09:46', 'car');
  ('19', '0', '09:50', 'car');
```

The question is **how to find the time when specific 'tracker_name' started his route**

So in my example algorithm in my head is:

- SELECT * FROM tab_gps WHERE tracker_name='car' then
- find the last position with speed=0 (which have next positions >0)
- and the next position is the TIME which I am looking for

In my example, it is a position **time: 09:41** (id = 17)

I am trying to use:

```
select max(time) from tab_gps where tracker_name='car' and speed <>0
```

Here is the Fiddle to better understanding: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/834371

Comment: It would be easier if the `time` column was an actual TIME data type

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes, we can say it is TIME. In my real example, it is 'DATETIME' format

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in question, which is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/834371

Comment: Then why did you say it was a VARCHAR(200)

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, just by mistake when I have copied the other field. If you knwo how to answer I will appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

Well, for the final route, you can do:

```
select g.*
from tab_gp2 g
where g.tracker_name = 'car' and
      g.id > (select coalesce(max(g2.id), -1)
              from tab_gps g2
              where g2.speed = 0 and g2.tracker_name = 'car'
             );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c81621bf402fc4aa5b5dc1fbe9e1c4dd) is a db<>fiddle illustrating the logic.

Comment: This returns zero records for me.

Comment: @gordon Linoff - this gave me a empty results as well, like Markov mentioned in above comment. Could you please check it?

Comment: @Tikky . . . Of course.  Your sample data ends in a `0`, so there are no rows after it.  You can look at the db<>fiddle to se an example that returns rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was my intention to add 0 in the end, cause I need a solution which bypasses this 0 and will show me the start time of the last trip, which is in this case ID=17

Comment: @Tikky . . . Personally, I think you should accept this answer -- which answers the question you originally asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will appreciate your help and time, but your solution it is not a workig answer, as I've especially mentioned in question: "In my example, it is a position time: 09:41 (id = 17)". I know that I can use simpler query, which also did not work as expected. The question in how to get a time of last trip. Last trip have spped > 0 and last posiition =0 km/h. I really appreciate if you are able to help. I am struggle with this problem. If I will not find the proper query I will try to that in pure PHP but this will be slower and more complicated. Looking forward to hear from you